# Is it possible to get a HP printer to work with or without hplip in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, printing, hp, hplip

I run Xubuntu 14.04 with a HP PSC 1315 printer, using hplip, and printing a document without the printer crawling to a halt is damn near impossible.

After a system reboot, printing one page sometimes succeeds without much hassle, but on any subsequent printing (whether it be the next page of the same document, or a new document altogether) the printer just crawls to a halt. The printer header moves very slow, with many pauses in between, and it takes ages (too long to wait) to print a subsequent page. Furthermore, text in those subsequent pages is usually blurry at the right edges as well.

I've tried too analyze the problem, but, frankly, the processes involved in printing a document are just too complex for me to figure out on my own.

One thing I've noticed though, is that a lot of print-related processes don't terminate, even if I cancel and clear all print jobs — I still see all kinds of printer-related zombie processes running in the task manager (multiple of the following):

```
gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOPAUSE ...
HP 52 <username> ...
hp:/usb/psc_1310_series?serial=<someserial> 52 <username> ...
```

(And usually the latter of these processes keep hogging the CPU, at around 60%-80%, as well)

It doesn't really matter what software I use to print a document:

- LibreOffice Write
- Evince (exported PDF from LibreOffice Write)
- Mousepad (just a simple, plain text, multi-paged document)

The ways I've set up my printer is through:

- Settings > Printers > Add
- `sudo hp-setup`

What I *did* notice though is that `sudo hp-check` reports:

> warning: ubuntu-14.04 version is not supported. Using ubuntu-13.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...

... listing all kinds of incompatibilities and/or missing libraries.

So, before delving deeper into this problem, I guess my first question is:

Am I just wasting my time in trying to get this printer to work on Xubuntu 14.04, because it is not supported?

Or:

Is it possible to get this printer to work on Xubuntu 14.04, either *with* or *without* using hplip?

Comment: According to HPLIP's websire, your printer is supported in Ubuntu. However, what I'd recommend doing s getting the latest version of HPLIP from their website. Download a new installer; it should work just fine with 14.04. Getting the latest HPLIP will hopefully solve this by getting bug fixes.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will give this a shot tomorrow, after a good night's rest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same exact model as you, but I do have an HP printer which works just fine without the HPLIP.  I can print and scan everything just fine.  The only thing I cannot do is check my ink levels and do other HP specific stuff, but for other everyday stuff I have zero problems.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 14.04 or later, HPLIP should already be the default driver that your PC is using.  All that's missing is the hplip GUI which can be installed through the ubuntu software center, just look up HPLIP GUI.  With the graphical user interface installed, you'll be able to check your ink levels.